# How to make a slideshow with audio tutorial in macbook

Tags: software-recommendation

I joined National social service's online learning initiative program of my college. I have to make videos which uses a slideshow presentation with audio. Something like khan academy videos but instead of writing, I need to use slides.

What all softwares should I install on my macbook?

Comment: What file output format are you looking for, .mp4? Slides would be easy to do in iMovie.

Comment: Mp4 is allowed.